# Form submission without blank data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, email

I have a form in at the footer section of my website, it email me basic user inputs and the current page url. Here is its layout

```
<form action="" id="myform" method="post">
    <input name="name" type="text" class="transparent-white-border-input" placeholder="Your Name">
    <input name="email" type="text" class="transparent-white-border-input" placeholder="Email Address">
    <textarea name="enquiry" class="transparent-white-border-input" rows="5" placeholder="Enquiry or Project Details...."></textarea>
    <input name="from_page" type="hidden" value="<?=$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]?>">
    <div class="send-btn">Send</div>
</form>
```

following is my ajax submission and javascript validation

```
<script>
$('.send-btn').click(function(){
    if(validateForm()){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax-request.php?function=footer_contact_form",
            type: "post",
            data: $("#myform").serialize(),
            success: function() {
                $(".emocean-contact-form .section-container").html('<h1 style="color: #fff; text-align:center;">Thank you for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly.</h1>');
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        alert("Please fill in all fields in blue.");
    }
})
function validateForm(){
    a=document.forms["myform"]["name"];
    a_regex=/\S/;
    d=document.forms["myform"]["email"];
    d_regex=/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/; //stackoverflow standard
    e=document.forms["myform"]["enquiry"];  
    e_regex= /\S/;

    valid = true;
    $("#myform input").css("backgroundColor", "");
    $("#myform textarea").css("backgroundColor", "");

    function check (origin, regex){
        if (!regex.test(origin.value)){
            origin.style.backgroundColor="blue";
            valid = false;          
        }   
    }

    check(a, a_regex);
    check(d, d_regex);
    check(e, e_regex);

    return valid;
}       
</script>
```

Here comes the problem. I tested in different devices and different browsers but everything works fine. But when it goes live sometimes it emails me with proper information just like in the test, but sometimes it sends me an email with all post data blanks, even $_post["from_page"] is blank. Don't know how this happened. I tried to submit this form in browser console to bypass the validation, while most fields are blank $_post["from_page"] still has value.

Also it didn't look like spam robots things since the blank emails are now coming quite often and they are all in random time. As mentioned before, some emails are not blank. Anyone with any idea what could possibly the problem be?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287257/stopping-empty-form-submission-php) might or might not be relevant.

Comment: You should add server-side validation. Then you could also check your hidden field against a session variable, reducing spam.

Comment: Agree with @jeroen ans also you may add captcha. Some spam scripts may just parse your form and send the data they want.

Comment: It would be quite possible for someone to use the developer tools and edit out your JavaScript check in order to send a blank form.  You could possibly use php to verify it a second time just to be sure.

Comment: @jeroen is it common to set up server site validation for all forms?

Comment: @EugeneGlova What i dont quite understand is what are the purpose of doing this

Comment: You **always** need server-side validation. Javascript can be manipulated, turned off, etc. as it is client-side.

Comment: @Anonymous why do they do this if they are not going to send me something they want instead they just send blank?

Comment: @LionLiu who knows. I think they are trying to find good form for submission but your doesn't have correct fields for them but they submit your form with blank values.

Comment: Who knows why people do anything such as hacking or annoying people with spam emails.  The important thing is to prevent it before it happens.

Comment: @LionLiu They are probably not trying to send the form to you, but are trying to see if they can get it to send to other addresses so that it can be used to spam.

Comment: OK, seems like this question has an easy fix. Thanks very much guys